# how to play embed youtube videos in video js player on firefox

Tags: jquery

Hi iam trying to play youtube embed code videos in my site using video.js player . It is working fine in chrome but when come to fire fox it is not working and embed code video is not playing . i dont know how to achievev it . can you please help me? Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

When you say "not playing", is there an error message that shows up? are there any errors in the console? 
Try turning off the tracking protection or try disabling any adblockers you might have.
Have a look here
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1108783

Comment: The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported. getting this error on player

Comment: Have you tried turning off the tracking protection or disabling the ad blockers? What format is the video? Also, please share any code that you're using.